# Plupload in metabox - AJAX action not working in Class

Tags: ajax, plupload

I'm trying to put the WP Pluploader into a meta box on my posts page - as per [Plupload Intergration in a meta-box?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33173/plupload-intergration-in-a-meta-box) and http://www.krishnakantsharma.com/2012/01/image-uploads-on-wordpress-admin-screens-using-jquery-and-new-plupload/

I got it all working as in the example in the second link. However, I want to put it all into a class file. It stops working if I wrap it all into a Class. And it's all because of:

```
function g_plupload_action()
{ 
    // check ajax noonce
    $imgid = $_POST["imgid"];
    check_ajax_referer($imgid . 'pluploadan');

    // handle file upload
    $status = wp_handle_upload($_FILES[$imgid . 'async-upload'], array('test_form' => true, 'action' => 'plupload_action'));

    // send the uploaded file url in response
    echo $status['url'];
    exit;
}
```

It works if this function is outside the Class and called through:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_plupload_action', "g_plupload_action");
```

But inside the Class and called with:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_plupload_action', array($this, 'g_plupload_action'));
```

and the return data is `0`.

What do I need to do in `function g_plupload_action()` to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, the problem as that I was calling the `wp_ajax_plupload_action` from within my page conditional check like so:

```
function __construct()
{
    global $pagenow;

    $pages = array('post.php', 'post-new.php');

    if (in_array($pagenow, $pages)) :

        add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'dhf_video_meta_box'));
        add_action('admin_print_scripts', array($this, 'video_meta_js'));
        add_action('admin_head', array($this, 'plupload_admin_head'));
        add_action('admin_print_scripts', array($this, 'video_meta_css'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_plupload_action', array($this, 'plupload_action'));

    endif;
}
```

You don't want to do it like that. Take the 
`add_action('wp_ajax_plupload_action', array($this, 'plupload_action'));` outside of that check and everything works again.